# How do I convert Q format integers to float (or vice versa)?

Tags: c++

I searched around and couldn't find a good SO question with a general answer to this question:

Given an integer using [Q Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)), how do I convert that number to a normal floating point type?

Or vice versa: how do I convert a floating point type into a [Q Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) integer?

For example, the Q2 integer `5` should be `1.25` in floating point, and the floating point number `1.25` should be the integer `5` in Q2 format.

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71361635/7224685

Answer (score 4):

The following is a general C++ solution:

```
template<class IntegerType>
float qToFloat(IntegerType q, int fractional_bits)
{
    return ((float) q) * std::pow(2, -fractional_bits);
}

template<class IntegerType>
IntegerType floatToQ(float q, int fractional_bits)
{
    return (int) (q * std::pow(2, fractional_bits));
}
```

Example usage:

```
qToFloat<uint16_t>(5, 2);     //1.25
floatToQ<uint16_t>(1.25f, 2); //5
```

Comment: For C : pow() exists in math.h. Use that rather than std::pow(). Works great!