# Getting Q15 float, (Float16?) from two bytes on Android (Java)

Tags: android

I have an input of bytes of pairs.

**One pair of byte represents a Q15 float.**

This is a format which I cannot change, it comes from a source that I have not control on.

**I would need to use the two bytes and build a Q15 float (Float16?) from them.**

My problem is that there is very few knowledge about this on stackoverflow or any other site.

I was trying to use Half, this is Android's own Float16 (or not?) but so far with less of a succes.

---

So for example I have a byte pair of: **113, 159,** these two are **-78.11234   in Q15 float.**

*This is the c code which generates these Q15 byte pairs which I get in Android from a source:*

```
#define Q15_SCALE_FACTOR (32768)

void float_array_2_q15_array(float* float_array, int16_t* q15_array, uint32_t array_length)
{
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < array_length; i++){
        q15_array[i] = (int16_t)(float_array[i] * Q15_SCALE_FACTOR);
        q15_array[i] = ((0xff00 & q15_array[i]) >> 8) | ((0x00ff & q15_array[i]) << 8);
    }
}
```

How can I convert the two given bytes (byte pairs) to make a Q15 float in Java (Android?)

---

**E d i t:**

Brief: My app getting this data stream from a greatly limited device, which is only able to store and send floats in 2 bytes instead of 4, because its greatly limited resources. (mostly memory) I'm in no power to change this condition. It is sending Q15 floats.

**Input:**

So the input is a List of primitive Java bytes which I read from this byte stream. I get them simply from iterating the given List.

```
 //Snippet from inside a loop with proper byte pair reading
 byte myByte = totalReadBytes.get(i);
 String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(myByte);
 int unsignedByte = Byte.toUnsignedInt(myByte);
```

The log looks like this. We have pair of bytes, each pair represents a Q15 Float, (Float16?)

```
=== Byte pair read from source: 
byte: 32, unsigned: 32, binary: 100000 
byte: 32, unsigned: 32, binary: 100000
=== Byte pair read from source: 
byte: -70, unsigned: 186, binary: 11111111111111111111111110111010 
byte: 97, unsigned: 97, binary: 1100001
=== Byte pair read from source: 
byte: -14, unsigned: 242, binary: 11111111111111111111111111110010 
byte: -48, unsigned: 208, binary: 11111111111111111111111111010000
=== Byte pair read from source: 
byte: 14, unsigned: 14, binary: 1110 
byte: 97, unsigned: 97, binary: 1100001
=== Byte pair read from source: 
byte: 113, unsigned: 113, binary: 1110001 
byte: -97, unsigned: 159, binary: 11111111111111111111111110011111
```

**The output** would be this. Theoratically, these are converted **byte pairs into Q15 floats.I have given this example with the input so I could test it.**

```
32, 32 -> 0.250981  
186, 97 -> 1.4561   
242, 208 -> -0.10304    
14, 97 -> 2.11234   
113, 159 -> -78.11234
```

So theoratically I would need something like a **Q15Float** class which would have a constuctor like

```
Q15Float(byte first, byte second)
```

**and this class would have to be able to print the given float of course.**

THANK YOU really much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification! I'm going over the examples there, and I'm not sure if the math works; can you indicate how you determined these output values? I have, in the same order as you, `0.250977`, `-0.543915`, `-0.103027`, `0.112335` and `0.887665`. As indicated in my answer, there isn't really any space left in a Q15 encoded short for anything to the left of the decimal point, so the values are in the range `-1.000000` to `0.999969`.

Comment: I'll ask the dev who makes the source. Probably a few days, thank you very much that you handle this problem of mine like your personal one. I'm really glad thank you very much.

Comment: All good. @mention me when you have an update and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

[Q formatted numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) are actually fixed precision numbers, with a number of bits set aside for the integer part, and a number for the fractional part. To be most specific, they are noted as `Qm.n` where the `m` represents the number of bits for the integer part, `n` those for the fractional part and the total number of bits required to store the number being `1 + m + n` (the additional bit being used to store the sign). The use of `Qn` without the `m` term simply means that `n` bits (in this case 15) are used to store the fractional part, and the sign and integer part comes out of the remaining bits.

The simplest answer, putting together the general conversion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678055/how-do-i-convert-q-format-integers-to-float-or-vice-versa) would be simply to take the `int16_t` output by that function (corresponding to a Java `short`) and divide by the same multiple (32768, which is `1 << 15`). This reverses the main part of your conversion.

However, as you may have guessed from the bit layout provided above, there will actually be no bits remaining for use in the integer part of the number. Thus, looking at the Q15 representation of your provided value (`-78.11234`), when stored in an `int16_t`, you get:

```
0xf19f
```

which, in binary, becomes:

```
0b1111000110011111
```

As you've specified there to be 15 bits for the fractional part of the number, we can separate the sign bit, and imagine a decimal point

```
-.111000110011111
```

This number is stored in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) so we can get the magnitude by inverting and adding one:

```
-.000111001100001
```

The integer value of the left hand side is `0` (as it doesn't exist) and the integer value of the left hand side is `3681`, so dividing by the full scale of the right hand size (`1 << 15` as above), and adding the left hand side we get:

```
-0.1123352051
```

To be able to represent values with that kind of integer magnitude, you'll likely want to move to a wider type, possibly still using 15 bits for the fractional part. If you move to an `int32_t`, you'll have enough bits to represent a much wider range of integer component values.

With the following code:

```
class Main {
  static {
    System.load("/path/to/Main.bundle");
  }

  static native short shortQ(int bits);
  static native int intQ(int bits);
  static native long longQ(int bits);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException {
    System.out.println("shortQ:");
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
      var result = shortQ(i);
      System.out.format("bits: %d = %f (%x)\n", i, ((float) result) / (1 << i), result);
    }

    System.out.println("intQ:");
    for (var i = 0; i < 32; i += 2) {
      var result = intQ(i);
      System.out.format("bits: %d = %f (%x)\n", i, ((float) result) / (1 << i), result);
    }

    System.out.println("longQ:");
    for (var i = 0; i < 64; i += 4) {
      var result = longQ(i);
      System.out.format("bits: %d = %f (%x)\n", i, ((double) result) / (1L << i), result);
    }
  }
}
```

```
#include <jni.h>

#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jshort JNICALL Java_Main_shortQ(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint bits) {
  float f = -78.11234 * (1 << bits);
  jshort result = (jshort)f;
  return f < 0 ? result | 0x8000 : result & 0x7fff;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_intQ(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint bits) {
  float f = -78.11234 * (1 << bits);
  jint result = (jint)f;
  return f < 0 ? result | 0x80000000 : result & 0x7fffffff;
}

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_Main_longQ(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint bits) {
  double f = -78.11234 * (1L << bits);
  jlong result = (jlong)f;
  return f < 0 ? result | 0x8000000000000000 : result & 0x7fffffffffffffff;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
shortQ:
bits: 0 = -78.000000 (ffb2)
bits: 1 = -78.000000 (ff64)
bits: 2 = -78.000000 (fec8)
bits: 3 = -78.000000 (fd90)
bits: 4 = -78.062500 (fb1f)
bits: 5 = -78.093750 (f63d)
bits: 6 = -78.109375 (ec79)
bits: 7 = -78.109375 (d8f2)
bits: 8 = -78.109375 (b1e4)
bits: 9 = -14.111328 (e3c7)
bits: 10 = -14.112305 (c78d)
bits: 11 = -14.112305 (8f1a)
bits: 12 = -6.112305 (9e34)
bits: 13 = -2.112305 (bc68)
bits: 14 = -0.112305 (f8d0)
bits: 15 = -0.112335 (f19f)
intQ:
bits: 0 = -78.000000 (ffffffb2)
bits: 2 = -78.000000 (fffffec8)
bits: 4 = -78.062500 (fffffb1f)
bits: 6 = -78.109375 (ffffec79)
bits: 8 = -78.109375 (ffffb1e4)
bits: 10 = -78.112305 (fffec78d)
bits: 12 = -78.112305 (fffb1e34)
bits: 14 = -78.112305 (ffec78d0)
bits: 16 = -78.112335 (ffb1e33e)
bits: 18 = -78.112343 (fec78cf6)
bits: 20 = -78.112343 (fb1e33d8)
bits: 22 = -78.112343 (ec78cf60)
bits: 24 = -78.112343 (b1e33d80)
bits: 26 = -32.000000 (80000000)
bits: 28 = -8.000000 (80000000)
bits: 30 = -2.000000 (80000000)
longQ:
bits: 0 = -78.000000 (ffffffffffffffb2)
bits: 4 = -78.062500 (fffffffffffffb1f)
bits: 8 = -78.109375 (ffffffffffffb1e4)
bits: 12 = -78.112305 (fffffffffffb1e34)
bits: 16 = -78.112335 (ffffffffffb1e33e)
bits: 20 = -78.112340 (fffffffffb1e33db)
bits: 24 = -78.112340 (ffffffffb1e33db0)
bits: 28 = -78.112340 (fffffffb1e33daf9)
bits: 32 = -78.112340 (ffffffb1e33daf8e)
bits: 36 = -78.112340 (fffffb1e33daf8e0)
bits: 40 = -78.112340 (ffffb1e33daf8df8)
bits: 44 = -78.112340 (fffb1e33daf8df7b)
bits: 48 = -78.112340 (ffb1e33daf8df7a4)
bits: 52 = -78.112340 (fb1e33daf8df7a40)
bits: 56 = -78.112340 (b1e33daf8df7a400)
bits: 60 = -8.000000 (8000000000000000)
```

showing the tradeoff in accuracy between the integer and fractional parts. Intuitively, and partly reflected in that listing, reserving half the type for each part seems like a good compromise.

Note that your `float_array_2_q15_array` function won't properly maintain sign when you start to exceed the integer value, if you want to ensure that sign is preserved (even in magnitude is truncated) you'll need to use something akin to the:

```
return f < 0 ? result | 0x8000 : result & 0x7fff;
```

lines in my code.

Also note that my code doesn't do the endianess conversion that your function does, as that is handled by JNI.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your answer but I have little to none knowledge about JNI. Can you help me do this implementation in plain Java? I would even pay for it if you give my your email address we can discuss it.

Comment: All good. If you edit your question to show both a) in code, how you are getting the numbers in Java (ie are they being entered from a file or by a user etc) and b) what exactly you'd like to do with them (could be some hypothetical code with comments etc). The C code that you'd included doesn't return a 2 byte pair, so it's not clear what the answer to both of those questions are. Cheers ✌️

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question, I tried to be as specific as I could be, please let me know If I should add something. Thank you really very much. I greatly appreciate your help.